# How to properly unload objects from memory in EmberJS?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a controller which contains an array that holds objects. 
Whenever I want to reload this array I use `controller.set('messages', []);`.

In my browser this works fine and does not cause the browser to crash. 
However on an iPad the app crashes after a few minutes. In my debug log I see a memory warning. My guess is that the objects remain in memory, which in time causes the app to crash. (I read somewhere that Safari on iPad has approx. 10MB memory limit for javascript object etc.)

Is this the correct way to clear data from an array, and remove all references to that object, so it can be garbage collected by the system?

Comment: You shouldn't guess when developer tools that come out of the box with Google Chrome are great for tracking memory leaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are running into some bindings not beeing removed and thus your memory problem. You could try one of the `Array` built-in methods like [`clear`](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.6/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/mutable_array.js#L56) this may does the right job.

For example:

```
controller.get('messages').clear();
```

This way the array will be re-used.

Please let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the [destroy](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.CoreObject.html#method_destroy) method on an Ember object.

ex:

```
var messages = controller.get('messages');
messages.forEach(function(message) {
  message.destroy();
});
messages.clear();
```